# Validation for name range overlapping.

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I have this requirement, and I am at my wits end. Any idea how to get this working ?

The field accepts a single value or a range to be part of the filter. Example of Ranges: "A-D", all the customers names with name starting with A, B, C or D; "SA-SP", all names starting with SA, SB, ..., SP; "MILG", all customer names with name starting with Milg;

While adding account names, the ranges should not overlap. Example: A-Q, P-Z is not valid since P-Q range is overlapping.

Comment: Show some code that you have tried?

Comment: So you also want to allow multiple ranges at once, e.g. `" A-k  , n-Q , W-za, Zc-Zw"`?

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure regex. A regular expression is not able to check if a matched character is "smaller" than a char matched before.

I would suggest to match the pattern, in c# something like this

```
^\p{L}+(-\p{L}+)?(?:,\s*\p{L}+(-\p{L}+)?)?$:
```

In Javascript replace `\p{L}` by `[A-Za-z]`

Then split by "," and check if

1. All found range patterns are valid ranges ==> the end of the first range is coming after the start (i.e. the start char is "smaller" than the end char).
2. The ranges do not overlap ==> start of the first range is outside the other ranges,  and if the end of the first range is also not within another range.